# Changed ROS2 environment variable FASTDDS_BUILTIN_TRANSPORTS to LARGE_DATA but now the topic is not listed in ROS2 topic list

Tags: ros2, data-distribution-service, transport

I am trying to switch the transport of ROS2 humble from UDP to TCP, so I set the environment variable
`FASTDDS_BUILTIN_TRANSPORTS` to `LARGE_DATA`, but now when I run the publisher node the topic to which the publisher publishes does not show in `ros2 topic list`

What I did was running a ROS2 publisher node in a ubuntu machine and tried to list the topics in the same machine in another terminal. the topics are not listed in another machine in the same network with the same `ROS_DOMAIN_ID`